# generating selectable pdf with Fast Report Dot net

Tags: pdf, .net-core, fastreport

I'm developing a dot net application in which I use Fast Report as pdf generator for customers invoices.

the generation process is working fine, the problem is that the pdfs generated by Fast Report are protected, meaning the texts are unselectable.
this made a problem for some of our customers when they receive the invoice, as they use have to extract the invoice information to insert it into their ERP.

is there an option in Fast Report to make the text in generated reports selectable.
if not is there any other Fast Report free alternative that can solve this.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It is  most likely the text is not "protected", actually PDF text cannot be protected unless your forced  to use an Adobe compatible viewer.

What you will probably find is it's an image-only PDF:

https://github.com/FastReports/FastReport/issues/421#issuecomment-1176022542

> This is a limitation of the PdfSimple version
> It exports to an image.

So your options are use a different means of output, that includes selectable fonts, OR use a different product but we do NOT suggest recommendations just because "free" products are usually not good enough for bulk users nor the bulk of users.

Comment: thank you @K J  for the answer. do you know any alternative whether its free or payed that can solve this issue ??